# Base 64 encode - twice

Tags: php, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I need to base 64 encode parts of a URL for an S3 URL.

I'm left with something like:

```
http://d111111abcdef8.cloudfront.net/image.jpg?color=red&size=medium
&Expires=1357034400
&Signature=nitfHRCrtziwO2HwPfWw~yYDhUF5EwRunQA-j19DzZrvDh6hQ73lDx~-ar3UocvvRQVw6EkC~GdpGQyyOSKQim-TxAnW7d8F5Kkai9HVx0FIu- 5jcQb0UEmatEXAMPLE3ReXySpLSMj0yCd3ZAB4UcBCAqEijkytL6f3fVYNGQI6
&Key-Pair-Id=APKA9ONS7QCOWEXAMPL
```

As you can see Signature and Key Pair ID are encoded.

I need to use the above URL as a param in another URL.

I have base64 encoded (as to mask the domain, makes it a liitle prettier) and then URL encoded this.

My question is, with having certain params base 64 encoded, then base 64 encoding the entire string again, upon decode, will the original params such as Signature and Key Pair ID be readable?

Comment: What you can encode to Base64, that you can decode from Base64.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple question, simple answer: Yes.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to do this, you will need to use "&" instead of "&" in the string you are encoding. Also, base64_decoding the entire encoded string, will only decode the last encoding.

An example:

```
$string1 = "This is a string";
$string2 = "This is another String";

$string1 = base64_encode( $string1 );
$string2 = base64_encode( $string2 );

echo $string1 . "<br />";

echo $string2 . "<br />";

$entity = "HTTP://www.google.com/?param1=" . $string1 . "&amp;param2=" . $string2;

$encoded_entity = base64_encode( $entity );

echo $encoded_entity . "<br />";

$decoded_entity = base64_decode( $encoded_entity );

echo $decoded_entity . "<br />";
```

This will output:

```
VGhpcyBpcyBhIHN0cmluZw==

VGhpcyBpcyBhbm90aGVyIFN0cmluZw==

SFRUUDovL3d3dy5nb29nbGUuY29tLz9wYXJhbTE9VkdocGN5QnBjeUJoSUhOMGNtbHVadz09JmFtcDtwYXJhbTI9VkdocGN5QnBjeUJoYm05MGFHVnlJRk4wY21sdVp3PT0=

HTTP://www.google.com/?param1=VGhpcyBpcyBhIHN0cmluZw==&param2=VGhpcyBpcyBhbm90aGVyIFN0cmluZw==
```

So as you can see, you can decode the entire string, but only the string you encoded will be decoded. Not all the levels of the encoded string. For that you will first have to decode the string, and then after that, decode the parameters.